# Crear un carrito de compras con VUEJS

Tags: vue.js, vuetify

estoy queriendo crear un carrito de compras.
Necesito que mi ciclo for recorra cada producto que agrego a una lista y sume el precio total de todos los productos juntos.

```
data: () => ({
  cantidad: 0,
  productos: [],
  resultado: 0,
  total: 0
}),

methods: {
  sumar(item){
// esto es solo para multiplicar el producto * cantidad elegida
    this.resultado = item.precioPublico * this.cantidad;
    console.log(this.resultado);

// guardo los datos del vmodel en Array
    const producto = {
      nombre: item.nombre,
      precio: item.precioPublico,
      cantidad: this.cantidad,
      total: this.resultado
    }

// lleno produtos con los datos almacenados anteriormente
    this.productos.push(producto)

// y esta es la parte que no me sale :(
    for(let i of this.productos){
        this.total += [i].precioPublico
    }
  }
},
```

aca una foto para que vean la idea principal
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: la verdad que de vue no se nada, pero lo que haria yo es que a la funcion que agrega un nuevo producto le agregaria un callback, entonces cuando agregues un nuevo producto mediante el callback agregas el nuevo producto a pagos totales

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba cambiar tu for

```
 for(let i of this.productos){
    this.total += [i].precioPublico
}
```

Por solo esto

```
 this.total += item.precioPublico;
```

o en tal caso por

```
  this.total += this.resultado;
```

Al ejecutar la funcion sumar ya no es necesario recorrer todo el arreglo, ya que cada elemento que agregues lo iras sumando al total.

Espero te sirva :)

Comment: gracias, me fue de mucha ayuda, la ultima opción fue la que me sirvió :)
`this.total += this.resultado`